# Actionscript 2 call function from variable

Tags: actionscript-2

How can i call a function form a variable.

```
var upfunction = init;
//or
var upfunction = init();
```

I have tried the above code and it does not work. I want to be able to call that variable from a keypress and change the variables function. For example.

```
function init(){
   //Do whatever
}

function init2(){
   //Do another thing
}

var upfunction = init();
if (Key.getCode() == Key.UP)
{
    upfunction;
}
```

Then later doing

```
upfunction = init2();
```

That way i could change the function without having much code. Sorry if this is a noob question but all i do is copy and paste code i have found.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right with what you've got... just remember that to **call** a function you need to include the brackets afterwards: 'upFuntion();'. Brackets are also needed when defining the function. The brackets will contain any function parameters.

But to refer to the function (such as when assigning it to a variable) you don't use the brackets: 'upFunction = init;'

So your example would look like this:

```
function init1():Void {
    trace("hello this is init1");
}

function init2():Void {
    trace("hey, this is init2");
}

var upFunction:Function = init1;//type declaration is optional but recommended

upFunction();// hello this is init1

upFunction = init2;

upFunction();//hey, this is init2
```